# Getting user info from a button on the client side with node

Tags: html, node.js, mongoose, ejs

I am creating a blog site where you can create your own blog and watch other peoples blogs, I have a page where you can see a list of the blogs and enter each blog, I am using ejs and with a for loop add a li tag for every blog, here is the ejs and html:

```html
<%- include('partials/header') %>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <ul class="list-group">
    <% users.forEach(function(Tuser) { %>
        <% if(Tuser.id != user.id) { %>
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <a href="/posts/othersblog"><h5><%= Tuser.username %></h5></a>
            </li>
        <% } %>
    <% }) %>
    </ul>
<%- include('partials/footer') %>
```

Tuser is every user which isnt you, and by clicking the a tag i want to get Tuser's ID or username, this is the app.post in the node part:

```js
//get someone else's blog
router.get('/othersblog',(req,res) => {
    res.render('othersblog',{
        headline: "Website | User Blog",
        title: "Blog",
        Tuser: req.Tuser,
    })
})
```

How do i get the Tuser so i can use it in the othersblog page(others people blog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a GET parameter on your route like this:

on your template:

```
<% users.forEach(function(Tuser) { %>
   <% if(Tuser.id != user.id) { %>
       <li class="list-group-item">
           <a href="<%= '/posts/othersblog/' + Tuser.username %>"><h5><%= Tuser.username %></h5></a>
       </li>
   <% } %>
<% }); %>
```

Then on your route:

```
router.get('/othersblog/:username',(req,res) => {
    res.render('othersblog',{
        headline: "Website | User Blog",
        title: "Blog",
        Tuser: req.params.username,
    });
});
```